# Motivation or intuition the identity $a=(b-(a-1)^{-1}b(a-1))(a^{-1}ba-(a-1)^{-1}b(a-1))^{-1}$, when $ab\neq ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In proving the Cartan-Brauer-Hua theorem, Hua uses an obscure identity. That is: 
$$
a=(b-(a-1)^{-1}b(a-1))(a^{-1}ba-(a-1)^{-1}b(a-1))^{-1}
$$
for $a$ and $b$ such that $ab \neq ba$. All these elements belong to a division ring.
This identity confused me.I want to know some motivation or intuition about this 
identity. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about what kind of objects $a$ and $b$ are? If everything commutes, this is not a well-defined statement. Otherwise it may be but it is still unclear which operations are permitted.

Comment: Conjugation in a group is not "obscure".

Comment: I think whatever this identity is, it's probably equivalent to Hua's identity? If so, you're re-asking [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602573/what-was-the-genesis-of-huas-identity), just with a different formulation of the identity.

Comment: @rschwieb,does this identity could be implied by Hua's identity?

Comment: @rschwieb I think Hua's identity could be deduced from $(1-ba)^{-1}=b(1-ab)^{-1}a+1$. This identity could be described that if $1-ab$ is invertible then so is $1-ba$. But I don't know why he choose the initial form.

Comment: @yuan It's been a long time since I looked into it, but I do think I remember Hua using a different version of the identity later attributed to him.  I think later authors simplified it to what I wrote.  I haven't attempted to prove their equivalence yet...

Comment: @yuan The reason I asked my question is I thought it is a little distasteful to juggle identities without clues to why they should work. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to rectify this much :(

Comment: I have added an answer to this question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602573/what-was-the-genesis-of-huas-identity

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3937032/29335) (a proof of the identity)