# What is the intuition behind Hua’s proof of the Cartan-Brauer-Hua theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, intuition, division-ring

The Cartan-Brauer-Hua theorem states that

> Let $K\subset D$ be division rings so that whenever $x\in D$ is a nonzero element, $xKx^{-1}\subset K$. Show that either $K\subset Z(D)$ or $K=D$.

This theorem is partially named after Hua due to his 1-liner proof:

> If $ab\neq ba$, then $$a=(b^{-1}-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1))(a^{-1}b^{-1}a-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1))^{-1}$$

It is all very nice, but the point is, how did all these come up? It is not obvious even if it has been written out, but how the h*ll was this constructed? What was the intuition?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3090668/29335.

Comment: I too have struggled with one of Hua’s identities, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1602573/29335) which coincidentally is linked to that question. I don’t know immediately if this is a version of the same identity.  I don’t know if anyone really has a good explanation...